# ElasticSearch to search in MySql database

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

What is the idea of using ES as search server and MySql as a database? I'm keeping in ES fields by which I want to search and field to link it to the mysql (for example ID). When I execute search in ES, I'll get a list of ids in mysql and then I'll get all objects from MySql by ids, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should index the fields you wish to be 'searchable' into Elasticsearch, along with a non analysed primary key which will allow you to retrieve the record from the database upon a user finding what they have searched for. You can set a field as unsearchable such as your `PK` by defining it's `index` setting to `no`, you can read about this [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html).

Another approach would be to keep your ES cluster synchronised with your MySQL database, meaning that any CRUD operations performed against your DB will replicate to your ES cluster. If you have a look at [rivers](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc&ei=8MtbU6nrJ4mfO7LhgSA&usg=AFQjCNGDiBupWpNhnB7l-1zzs8SGq5zy2Q&bvm=bv.65397613,d.ZWU) you can poll your DB at pre-defined intervals.